# Grub rescue preventing me to install/boot new os from usb stick

Tags: dual-boot, grub, boot-loader, bootable

I have a HP laptop.I was having dual boot window 10 and ubantu. then i deleted ubantu partition along with grub boot partition.

I have USB bootable stick which filesystem is of type ExFat.

I made it bootable by command - `sudo dd bs=4M if=~/Desktop/Windows-64bit.iso of=/dev/sdx conv=fdatasync  status=progress`

now i can not even boot the usb stick beacuse it goes to screen of `grub rescue`.

i have tried all the the methods to fix grub like using grub commands - `ls`, `set`, `normal` etc. none of them worked for me.

Now i Just want a fresh install of window only as i think fixing grub wouldn't work.

please suggest me the solution so that i can boot USB Stick.

Comment: Windows ISO does not support use of dd to create a bootable flash drive. Best to use Windows tools as its .wim file is over 4K and cannot be on FAT32 partition. And you need a FAT32 partition for UEFI boot. Windows tools split the .win file to make it work.

Comment: I have verified it with my other asus laptop, it is working the usb is booting windows. please elaborate your answer, or tell me how to do so in steps.